# Cloud SQL Stuck on restart

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Cloud SQL stuck after resizing and subsequent restart and nothing I do gets it unstuck

I've tried Google Shell to stop, restart or then start via cli and no luck

How do I get support from Google for a Cloud SQL instance stuck nn GCP

Comment: By some miracle I had a 1cpu Cloud SQL replica running on a 16cpu instance and it got stuck when I resized to 8cpu. 
- promoted the 1cpu replica to master
- changed over wordpress to point to the new IP
That little bugger saved the day so if you are going to make changes create a read replica first then update/restart then you will have a fallback.

Comment: So the instance is stuck on restarting, still, just running on it's own and still no support anywhere after submitting in 3 places and sending an email to suggested support email for Cloud SQL. Not happy to say the least.

Comment: Could you open a private issue by following this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274)? Please include in the new private case references to any open cases you might have regarding this issue.